# Scrollspy effect in Angular router

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-routing

I'm trying to add the Scrollspy effect to the Angular project. When a user click a link, rather than show it as a new page, that component should scroll up and the next component should come to that place. Is there a way to do it in Angular with routing? When a link get clicked, the page should animate to scrolltop as with the following jquery code

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offsetTop}, 'normal');
```

Is there any libraries or features in Angular?

Comment: Check out this library, I used it recently and it worked like a charm: https://github.com/nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to

Comment: @StefanSvrkotaThank you, this seems to be the one that I'm looking for but my request is will it possible to use with the routing? because what it does is to scroll to the specified hash location

Comment: You can surround your `router-outlet` with `div`, give that `div` an id and then use the library I provided to scroll to that `div`. That way, it will always scroll to top. Scroll is smooth by the way, so this is a very nice library.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota Thank you for the suggestion, I will try that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for something very simple to handle scrolling, I ended up making my own directive :

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollSpy]'
})
export class ScrollSpyDirective {
  @Input() public spiedTags = [];
  @Output() public sectionChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
  private currentSection: string;

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event: any) {
    let currentSection: string;
    const children = this._el.nativeElement.children;
    const scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
    const parentOffset = event.target.offsetTop;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      const element = children[i];
      if (this.spiedTags.some(spiedTag => spiedTag === element.tagName)) {
        if (element.offsetTop - parentOffset <= scrollTop) {
          currentSection = element.id;
        }
      }
    }
    if (currentSection !== this.currentSection) {
      this.currentSection = currentSection;
      this.sectionChange.emit(this.currentSection);
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is a demo link with routing integrated.](https://angular-scroll-spy-routing.stackblitz.io/section1) For some reason, [the stackblitz edition version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-spy-routing) breaks the stackblitz editor scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version for Angular 9:

```js
import { Directive, Input, EventEmitter, Output, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[scrollSpy]'
})

export class ScrollSpyDirective {
    @Input() public spiedTags = [];
    @Output() public sectionChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
    private currentSection: string;

    constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}

    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    onScroll(event: any) {
        let currentSection: string;
        const children = this._el.nativeElement.children;
        const scrollTop = event.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
        const parentOffset = event.target.scrollingElement.offsetTop;
        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            const element = children[i];
            if (this.spiedTags.some(spiedTag => spiedTag === element.tagName)) {
                if ((element.offsetTop - parentOffset) <= scrollTop) {
                    currentSection = element.id;
                }
            }
        }

        if (currentSection !== this.currentSection) {
            this.currentSection = currentSection;
            this.sectionChange.emit(this.currentSection);
        }
    }
}
```